# <link rel="shortcut icon"> validation error despite being valid

Tags: html, favicon, w3c-validation

The w3.org validator is giving me an error on the following line:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This is the full error it gives:

> Line 1, Column 727: **Bad value `shortcut icon` for attribute rel on element link: The string `shortcut` is not a registered keyword. The string `shortcut` is not an absolute URL.**
>
> …f="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /**>**
>
> Syntax of link type valid for :
>
> > A whitespace-separated list of link types listed as allowed on  in the HTML specification or listed as an allowed on  on the Microformats wiki without duplicate keywords in the list.
> >
> > You can register link types on the Microformats wiki yourself.
>
> Syntax of absolute IRI: An absolute URL.
>
> > For example: http://example.org/hello, but not /hello. Spaces should be escaped as %20.

What I don't understand is that I'm following the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-icon) which says:

> For historical reasons, the `icon` keyword may be preceded by the
>   keyword "`shortcut`". If the "`shortcut`" keyword is present, it must be
>   come immediately before the `icon` keyword and the two keywords must be
>   separated by only a single U+0020 SPACE character.

I see that it is suggesting the `%20` as a space, which I've tried:

```
<link rel="shortcut%20icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

But when I use this code, the error I get is nearly the same, except it starts out:

> Error Line 1, Column 729: **Bad value `shortcut%20icon` for attribute rel on element link: The string `shortcut%20icon` is not a registered keyword. The string `shortcut%20icon` is not an absolute URL.**

Comment: This was validating yesterday. It may be a bug in the validator or there's been a change of policy.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with the W3C validator. All my HTML5 projects – they were valid last week – throw the same error as mentioned today. Using an alternative validator (e.g. the [Validator.nu (X)HTML5 Validator](http://html5.validator.nu)) everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I received this message today from Steve Faulkner.

> It was due to a bug in the validator, its has been fixed and will be
> pushed tomorrow.
>
> Steve Faulkner
>
> TPG Distinguished Accessibility Engineer
>
> -
>
> Co-editor HTML 5.1

Comment: Looks like it hasn't changed yet. Is Steve Faulkner the person who maintains the validator?